# QGIS linestring length as meters from degrees(map unit)

Tags: pyqgis, linestring

I wrote a code that gives the line string length as degrees but I need the unit as meters. I can't convert it to meters from degree.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for i in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = i.geometry()

    lineLength = geom.length()
    print(lineLength )
```

Comment: Convert your data to a fitting CRS (not 3857), then get the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `QgsDistanceArea` class to handle the curved nature of the Earth's surface.

From the [manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html):

```
d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')

# Let's create two points.
# Santa claus is a workaholic and needs a summer break,
# lets see how far is Tenerife from his home
santa = QgsPointXY(25.847899, 66.543456)
tenerife = QgsPointXY(-16.5735, 28.0443)

print("Distance in meters: ", d.measureLine(santa, tenerife))

for i in layer.getFeatures():
    geom = i.geometry()
    print("length of a line in m", d.measureLength(geom))
```

Comment: Thanks, sir. It works.